# My query does not work. Type "double" does not exist

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I tried that:

```
@Query("SELECT AVG(a.unitPrice) FROM ConnectwiseAgreementAdditions a WHERE a.agreementId = :agreementId " +
        "AND a.productId IN (SELECT p.id FROM ConnectwiseProductFindResult p " +
        "WHERE LOWER(p.subCategory) LIKE LOWER('%server%') " +
        "OR LOWER(p.subCategory) LIKE LOWER('%workstation%'))")
BigDecimal geAgreementDevicetUnitPrice(@Param("agreementId") Integer agreementId);
```

But i have exception:

2016-05-11 14:58:05.773 ERROR 28016 --- [main] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper             : ERROR: type "double" does not exist
  Position: 44
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

What is wrong?
I use Postgresql driver.

**UPDATE**
My entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "connectwise_agreement_additions")
public class ConnectwiseAgreementAdditions {
@Id
@Column
private Integer id;

@Column(columnDefinition = "DEFAULT false")
private boolean normalize = false;

@Column(name = "agreement_id", columnDefinition = "NUMERIC(18,2)")
private Integer agreementId;

@Column(name = "product_id")
private Integer productId;

@Column(name = "unit_price", columnDefinition = "NUMERIC(18,2)")
private BigDecimal unitPrice;
}
```

Comment: Please post DDL of entity ConnectwiseAgreementAdditions

Comment: You are stuffing numerical prices with 2 digits after the dot into a BigDecimal with no digits after the dot, this cannot possibly be what works well.

Comment: Please check your hibernate dialect. PostgreSQL has no `double` type indeed, it is called `double precision`. Also: `Integer agreementId` has a column definition of `NUMERIC(18,2)` which makes little sense (but may work), and `boolean normalize` should have something like `columnDefinition = "BOOLEAN DEFAULT false"`, not just the default.

Comment: You can use the datatype float, which a shorthand alias for double precision.

Answer (score 0):

Simple include this in the **application.properties**:

`spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect`